# Truly Clean installation on HP Pavilion DV7 3085DX

Tags: windows-7, laptop, partitioning

First of all I own an HP DV7 3085DX laptop, as the title states, and one of the coolest features I've encountered with HP laptops (I don't know if any other laptops have this feature) is the ability to restore the laptop to its original factory settings.

Sadly most laptops have bloatware and HP laptops have a LOT, so I've been researching online about making a clean installation while keeping the Windows 7 (x64 Home Premium, in my case) OEM activation.

I came across this guide '[The HP Laptop Out-Of-The-Box Guide 2.0 for Windows 7](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-compaq/432564-hp-laptop-out-box-guide-2-0-windows-7-a.html)' which *teaches* you how to do this in a series of steps (Back up 'SwSetup' folder in the root, usually c:, Create Recovery Discs, Install & activate Windows with your **original** key).

I've created the recovery disks, backed up the SwSetup folder, and I'm about to install windows without using the Recovery Manager, to achieve a really clean installation.

Now, my questions:

- I'm not formatting the 'D' partition aka RECOVERY, but `what's the point of having that partition if I've created the Recovery Discs **and** backed up the SwSetup folder?`
- I think, more than I really know, that partition is used when you actually use the Recovery Manager, but I wont be having that tool available by doing a **clean** installation so `is there any reason not to format & merge the RECOVERY partition to the C drive?`
- I've never used the recovery discs so `will I get the same *result* using the recovery discs **or** the recovery manager?`
- And the most important questions are `what happens if I delete the recovery partition and try to use the recovery discs?` `Will this recreate the RECOVERY partition?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave the recovery partition in tact until you install using the discs at least once. The system's BIOS is capable of booting that partition, so if something is wrong with one of your discs, the system is still recoverable.

If you're using discs generated via HP's recovery utilities, they will, most likely, still include the bloatware. Their entire recovery process hinges off of a base image that is taken, what media is used to install it (the hidden partition or discs) is generally irrelevant.

To get a truly "clean" install you would need to acquire an ISO image of an OEM system-builder's Windows 7 x64 Home Premium disc and install from that, providing the key that should be on a sticker on your computer somewhere when prompted.

The only caveat to doing that, especially if this is your only computer in the house, is to make sure you visit HP's web site and download device drivers for your network adapter (wireless or wired) and stick them on a flash drive prior to doing the installation. It's not at all uncommon for Windows 7 (now a few years old) to not have a device driver for a newer network adapter.

Comment: I have an original Windows 7 Home Premium x64 dvd, I'm planning on install from that and use the key of my laptop, for now I'll leave the Recovery partition as you suggested. Thanks!